# how to merge array to the json to form a expected result

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, express

I have an JSON array with me:

```
var row={ shopId: 3, shopName: '1', address: 'abc', contactNumber: 1234 }
```

I have a array with me:

```
var data= [ { imageId: 1, shopId: 3, imageUrl: 'aaa' },
            { imageId: 2, shopId: 3, imageUrl: 'bbb' } ]
```

I have to merge these two and make a output like this:

```
var result = {
    shopId: 3,
    shopName: '1',
    address: 'abc',
    contactNumber: 1234,
    image: [{
        imageId: 1,
        shopId: 3,
        imageUrl: 'aaa'
    }, {
        imageId: 2,
        shopId: 3,
        imageUrl: 'bbb'
    }]
}
```

Comment: Can you not just do `row.image = data;`?

Comment: should the result be a new object? is row part of an array and is in data more than only one item with the same shopid?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a "shop" object that also contains a list of images associated with the shop. If that's so, then your "data" array looks to only contain items with the same "shopId" value. Is that assured, or do you need to, as Jose has suggested, filter the "data" array? Also, why do you need your result "image" array to contain the "shopId" value? That's assumed from its parent object "shopId".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign your `data` to `row.image` like this:

```js
var row = {
  shopId: 3,
  shopName: '1',
  address: 'abc',
  contactNumber: 1234
}

var data = [{
  imageId: 1,
  shopId: 3,
  imageUrl: 'aaa'
}, {
  imageId: 2,
  shopId: 3,
  imageUrl: 'bbb'
}]

var result = row.image = data;

console.log(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write either `row['image'] = data;` or `row.image = data;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` if data contains objects with `shopId`s other than 3 :

```js
    var row={ shopId: 3, shopName: '1', address: 'abc', contactNumber: 1234 }

    var data= [ { imageId: 1, shopId: 3, imageUrl: 'aaa' },
                { imageId: 2, shopId: 3, imageUrl: 'bbb' },
                { imageId: 2, shopId: 5, imageUrl: 'bbb' }];

row.images = data.filter( el => el.shopId == row.shopId);

console.log(row);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to modify the originals you may also do like

```js
var  row = { shopId: 3, shopName: '1', address: 'abc', contactNumber: 1234 },
    data = [ { imageId: 1, shopId: 3, imageUrl: 'aaa' }, { imageId: 2, shopId: 3, imageUrl: 'bbb' } ],
   combo = Object.assign({},row,{["image"]:data});
console.log(combo);
```